# dynamically create simpy.resource

Tags: python, simpy

I am currently creating simpy.resource using the following command:

```
str1_counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
```

But if I want to create it in a dynamic manner based on user input i.e. lets say user says the capacity(variable cap) should be 4, so in that case I tried the following:

```
cap = input("Enter the capacity of the store")
str1_counter = 'simpy.Resource(env, capacity=' + cap + ')'
```

But as you can see that instead of an instance of simpy.resource being created, the result is a string called `'simpy.Resource(env, capacity=4)'` although I would have wanted `simpy.resource(env,capacity=4)`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as such;

```
cap = input("Enter the capacity of the store")
str1_counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=cap)
```

But also be aware of checking the input and catching errors.. for example if someone enters `five` instead of `5`, what should happen?

Comment: @bakas it happens to the best of us ;) don't forget to tick if it's ok!

Comment: Just use `capactiy=int(cap)` to do some basic input validation.

Comment: However this will throw an error if `cap` is not an int instance. Better to check `isinstance(cap, int)` and manage from there.